# c# datagridview Сравнение ячеек в столбце если значение не совпадает поменять цвет

Tags: datagridview, сравнение

Привет. Нужно сравнить 2 столбика из DataGridView и если значения в столбиках различается, в столбике котором меняются значения, покрасить другой цвет.
Вот мой код, но работает не корректно:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < advancedDataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
            for (int j = advancedDataGridView2.RowCount+1; j > i; j--)
                if (advancedDataGridView2[4, i].Value.ToString().Trim() == advancedDataGridView2[5, j].Value.ToString().Trim())
                    advancedDataGridView2[5, j].Style.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
                else advancedDataGridView2[5, j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

В чём моя ошибка ?

```
for (int j = advancedDataGridView2.RowCount+1; j > i; j--)
```

указав -1 тоже не работает

Comment: А зачем вы используете метод `Trim()`? И поясните подробнее условие. Потому что предложение "если значения в столбиках различается, в столбике котором меняются значения, покрасить другой цвет." лично мне непонятно. Что значит "в столбике котором меняются значения" и что нужно покрасить в другой цвет? весь столбик или одну ячейку столбика.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно поставлен вопрос, но, думаю, решение должно быть таким

```
        for (int i = 0; i < advancedDataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < advancedDataGridView2.RowCount; j++)
            {
                if (advancedDataGridView2[0, i].Value.ToString() == advancedDataGridView2[1, j].Value.ToString())
                    advancedDataGridView2[1, j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, вот код если кому нибудь пригодится:

```
for (int i = 0; i < advancedDataGridView2.RowCount; i++)
        {
            advancedDataGridView2[5, i].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (advancedDataGridView2[4, i].Value.ToString().Trim() == advancedDataGridView2[5, i].Value.ToString().Trim())
                advancedDataGridView2[5, i].Style.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon;
            else advancedDataGridView2[5, i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```